# Why does the TextBlock.Foreground property in XAML not accept a Color?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-interface, markup-extensions

I've tried to run the samples, similar to the ones that Charles Petzold demonstrated in his [speech](https://evolve.xamarin.com/session/56e201d2bad314273ca4d813), but unfortunately, I can't get the TextBlock's Foreground property to accept my custom `MarkupExtension`, which simply returns a Color:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <StackPanel >
        <TextBlock Foreground="{local:MyConverter}"
                   Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference slider}, 
                                  Path=Value, 
                                  StringFormat='Rotation = {0:F2} degree'}">
        </TextBlock>
        <Slider x:Name="slider" Minimum="-360" Maximum="360"></Slider>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

with the following simply Markup-Extension:

```
class MyConverter : MarkupExtension
{
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {            
        return System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    }
}
```

Upon starting the application, I get a `XamlParseException` with an inner Exception that states: ***{"'Color [Red]' is not a valid value for property 'Foreground'."}***

I've also tried returning a solid brush: `return new SolidBrush(Color.Red);`, but with the same effect. What am I doing wrong? And how can I get my Foreground property to accept a Color-object as value? Do I need another conversion into a string?

Comment: Isn't `Foreground` of type `System.Media.Brushes`?

Comment: cause it use brushes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class MyConverter : MarkupExtension
{
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {            
        return System.Media.Brushes.Red;
    }
}
```

I think `TextBlock.ForeGround` is of type `System.Media.Brushes` which contains similar base colors.

Comment: I used the wrong namespace for Color and Brush `System.Drawing` instead of `System.Windows.Media`.

Answer (score 1):

Because `Foreground` is not a `Color` but `Brush`.

> public Brush Foreground { get; set; }

[source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.foreground%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

You can handle this with a converter or look for an answer in this thread: [How to convert color code into media.brush?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6808739/how-to-convert-color-code-into-media-brush)

Answer (score 1):

you could try something like this

```
textBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run("Red") { Foreground = Brushes.Red });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
class MyConverter : MarkupExtension
{
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    }
}
```