# Convert from string to Thickness, GridLength, Brush... in UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Is there a built-in class to do the conversion from a string to those common types?

For example, to convert "1,2,3,4" to a `Thickness` or "#00AABBCC" to a `Brush`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No.** There are no built-in from-string-converters for `Thickness` or `Brush` in UWP.

But [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36794446/1830814) how you can create a `StringToSolidColorBrushConverter`.

And [here's](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/ThicknessConverter.cs) the source code of .NET's `System.Windows.ThicknessConverter`. Though, it works only in .NET Framework, you can  take the converter algorithm from the `FromString(..)` method.

Answer (score 1):

Old post, but anyone looking for this, you can use

```
(Thickness)XamlBindingHelper.ConvertValue(typeof(Thickness), value)
```

Not just for thickness, but for lots of types. This is also working in WinUI3

[XamlBindingHelper documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.markup.xamlbindinghelper?view=winrt-22621)